# Ruby on rails .authentication failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, api, authentication

I'm building an API for a web app I'm developing, and the following code I'm trying to use for API authentication/login is returning false on the authorization.

In my API user controller I have:

```
def login
  if params[:user]
    # Find the user by email first
    @user = User.where(email: params[:user][:email]).first
    if !@user
      respond_with nil
    else
      @auth = @user.authenticate(params[:user][:password])
      if @auth
        respond_with @user
      else
        respond_with @auth
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It is always responding with @auth, which is false, even when valid email and passwords are being provided. It has no problem pulling the user info from my Mongo db.

I guess I'm just not clear on what .authenticate does. According to a railscast.com video I watched, it should compare that users password digest with the password entered. When a valid password is provided for the user, @auth is always false.

Comment: is this from railscast #250? If so, don't you also need to pass an email to the authenticate function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method was actually working fine, the test data in the database wasn't what i thought it was..